# Filter Objects that are related to an object by another relationship

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

```
class Shipping (models.Model):
    phone_number =  models.CharField(max_length=14)
    email = models.EmailField()

class Package(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    supplier = models.ForeignKey( Supplier , on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    to =  models.ForeignKey(Shipping, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE )
```

I have these Django models and as you see every package has shipping(to) and a supplier who is a user. How can I filter Shipping objects that are related to the package with a specific supplier in my views?

I want to be able to get all Shipping objects a supplier has ever send packages to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
Shipping.objects.filter(package__supplier=<supplier_object>)
```

Basically you can run reverse query from Shipping to Package models via `package__<field_name>` attribute(model name all lowecase unless you have defined a related name, then it would be `<related_name>__<field_name>`.

More information can be found in [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#related-objects).

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can do something like the following thing:

```
  shippings = []
  for package in Package.objects.filter(supplier=supplier_you_want).all():
     shippings.append(package.to)
```

hope that could help!

Answer (score 0):

The below line will return all the shippings corresponding to your_supplier.

```
shippings=Package.objects.filter(supplier=your_supplier).values('to__phone_number','to__email')
```